# searching an ArrayList and returning the output to another ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

i have an ArrayList of "movie" object
i wanted to search in it by "name" which is one of the attributes of the movie object

thats the code used for searching

```
     ArrayList<movie> matches = new ArrayList<movie>();
                // go through list of members and compare name with given name
                for(movie movie : MovieReg_activity.movies) {
                Log.d("searchBar", searchbar); 
                Log.d("Movie Name", movie.getName());
                    if (movie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchbar)) {
                        matches.add(movie); // adds matching member to the return list
                    }
                }
                int match_size=matches.size();
                tv.setText("no of matches=" +match_size);
```

match_size always equals to zero !

thats the class movie

```
public class movie {

    String name;
    int dvd_no ;

    public movie( String name1 , int dvd_no1) 
    {
                this.name = name1 ;
            this.dvd_no = dvd_no1 ; 

    }

    String getName()
    {
        return this.name ;
    }

}
```

what is the problem with that code?

logcat

```
02-17 04:28:38.500: I/Process(638): Sending signal. PID: 638 SIG: 9
02-17 04:30:27.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(720): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 04:30:27.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(720): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 04:43:35.531: W/KeyCharacterMap(747): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 04:43:35.531: W/KeyCharacterMap(747): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 04:55:23.350: W/KeyCharacterMap(774): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 04:55:23.360: W/KeyCharacterMap(774): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 04:58:04.050: W/KeyCharacterMap(801): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 04:58:04.050: W/KeyCharacterMap(801): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 04:59:40.970: W/KeyCharacterMap(828): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 04:59:40.970: W/KeyCharacterMap(828): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 05:01:25.971: W/KeyCharacterMap(881): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 05:01:25.971: W/KeyCharacterMap(881): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 05:01:49.500: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(881): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-17 05:02:54.722: W/KeyCharacterMap(908): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 05:02:54.722: W/KeyCharacterMap(908): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 05:24:44.560: W/KeyCharacterMap(935): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 05:24:44.560: W/KeyCharacterMap(935): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 05:27:29.980: W/KeyCharacterMap(962): No keyboard for id 0
02-17 05:27:29.980: W/KeyCharacterMap(962): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-17 05:27:37.289: D/searchBar(962): fawzy
02-17 05:29:33.540: D/searchBar(962): fawzy
```

Comment: is case sensitivity important? if not, then change your if statment to if (movie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchbar)){...

Comment: Are you sure searchbar is what you want to search for?  Is its type a String?  Or did you want to do searchbar.getText() or the like?

Comment: or even `searchbar.getText().trim()`. Did you try debugging through your code?

Comment: @panini even it's the same word exactly always equals zero

Comment: @GabeSechan yes..sure

Comment: Before your If Statement, `Log.d("searchBar", searchBar); Log.d("Movie Name", movie.getName()");`  Will show you what it is comparing.

Comment: @nathansizemore "search bar" only shown in the logcat !!

Comment: You get no reading for "Movie Name", or is it just blank?

Comment: no reading at all ! no "movie Name" tag at all !!

Comment: Does it break and throw an exception?

Comment: @Fawzinov post your updated code in the OP so we can work out what it is you are doing.

Comment: @panini ok .. posted updates and logcat

Comment: Try `Log.d("Movie Object". movie.toString());`  See what movie really is...

Comment: 02-17 05:43:59.900: D/Movie Object(989): com.fawzyx.movie_rental_store.movie@45f5e9b0

Comment: im not giving the movie objects names .. its created by a click

Comment: The last debug query I can think of is, before your loop starts, `Log.d("Debug Test", MovieReg_activity.movies.get(0).getName());`  If that doesn't print.  I would recommend saving, restarting Eclipse, and try it again.  Logcat isn't the most dependable package.  It is pretty buggy.

Comment: @nathansizemore the same even after restarting eclipse and the avd :( .. anyway thanks:(

Answer (score 1):

Try using `equalsIgnoreCase` in the test for the movie name. As it is you must have an exact case match.

And you might consider using `indexOf` after converting both strings to lower case to do a contains search.

Comment: Then add a debug print of the two values in the loop and ensure they are what you expect.

Comment: Movie.getName doesn't return !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "MovieReg_activity.movies" is not empty? If it is empty your matches list does not assign any movie objects. That might be the reason always you get 0 for matches.size(). Check and make sure MovieReg_activity.movies is not empty.